# How to get all hyperlink urls and create onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have to get 3 hyperlinks in javascript based only on their `href` and create an `onClick` event. In other words, I need to do two things with the below urls:

1. Get all three `a` elements based on their URLs, for instance  `href1,href2,href3`
2. Create an `onClick` event, for example `href1.onClick` calls `alert("I am from India");`

URLs:

```
<a class="" href="/MyProject/Information/EmpDetails.aspx?userId=79874&countryId=875567" title="">India</a>


<a class="" href="/MyProject/Information/EmpDetails.aspx?userId=98667&countryId=98755" title="">Australia</a>


<a class="" href="/MyProject/Information/EmpDetails.aspx?userId=76456&countryId=87463" title="">New Zealand</a>
```

Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What efforts have you made already?

Comment: with my understanding of your requirement I have created a fiddle, please try and let me know.http://jsfiddle.net/nightswatch/mk56c3t7/

Comment: Hi NightsWatch, Thanks for providing me the answer it looks good but my requirement is to get all the href1,href2 and href3 if someone clicks on India it should give alert you are from india if from australia you are from Australia

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to to improve its readability and make it less confusing for other people trying to answer. I also indented the code mixed in the text so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please also add as an edit the specific steps you've taken in trying to solve this problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery attribute selector to find the elements, like:

```
$("a[href$='countryId=875567']").click(function(){ 
    alert("countryId=875567");
});
```

This will get all hyperlinks that ends with *countryId=875567*.

If you want the exact href you should use:

```
$("a[href='http://example.com.br/test']").click(function(){ 
     alert("test");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/v3qpy3gL

Hope it helps.